# Chrome Extension API access

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm developing a chrome extension which access an external(3rd party) API with return type of CSV (`someurl/api.php?op=get&op2=events&return_type=csv`). I couldn't find any relevant ways to do the access. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Need some help ASAP.` is not just inpolite. It's rude. We help you for free. Accept that or go and pay for priority support somewhere else.

Comment: @KonradDzwinel  I tried using Jquery $.get() [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).But Its not giving the expected output.

Comment: @jgauffin I apologize. But It would be helpful if you try to help me out with this question.

Comment: @KonradDzwinel '  var jqxhr = $.get("http://localhost/test/test.php", function(data) {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= data;
});
}' this is the function i used. It works fine when I use it to a html page and access as web page. But not giving any output when I move it to extension. It will be helpful if you can help me out with how to use the similar kind of function in extensions.

Comment: @Hareesh Do not post huge chunks of code as comments. Instead update your question with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your extension has sufficient permissions, then make an AJAX request, then process CSV using some JavaScript CSV library or a regex.

Everything is in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html). You may also find relevant examples [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html).